# event.target.toString() or event.target.nodeName to check type of element

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an eventlistener with delegation (like jQuery $("body").on("click", "button")). For that i have following event listener:
`document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {})`

Now i wonder, which way is the best way to check for the type of the clicked element. Is it checking for it nodeName:

`if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "button") { return; }`

or would that solution be better:

`if (e.target.toString() !== document.createElement("button").toString()) { return; }`

?

I think, the first solution could be perform better, but the second one could be more secure? And please think of document.create... as an variable outside the click event, for performance reason.

**Answer**
Thanks to zippy dippy (how do i link accounts?) for his answer and introducing `e.target.matches("button")` as alternative. As already thought the check for the nodeName is still the best answer. But i like to try new things and that how my question rose up.

I did a little check on Element.matches because i haven´t heard of it until now. For a pure type check (like in my question) the nodeName check is still the fastes way, except for Firefox. At least if i take http://jsben.ch/RL5PN as valid benchmark. In Chrome Element.matches took almost double as long as nodeName. In Safari both of them are on equal ground, in Firefox Element.matches the fastest. But for more complexes case like `button.someClass[data-foo=someValue]` nothing beats Element.matches of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.nodeName`. It is well supported, fast and is the standard approach.

Also, you don't need `.toLowerCase()`. The `.nodeName` is guaranteed to return an uppercase string, at least for standard elements, so change your comparison to this:

```
e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON"
```

Another approach would be to use the selector engine. Since this is for delegation, it'll give you more flexibility:

```
e.target.matches("button")
```

Because you're using the selector engine, you can provide any valid Selectors API selector.

```
e.target.matches("button.someClass[data-foo=someValue]")
```

Some older browsers had this behind a flag for a while with the method name `.matchesSelector` (preceded by the appropriate browser flag prefix). You can easily patch the standard `.matches` with the flagged version where needed.